# Angular error when applying css style: Refused to apply style from 'path' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to create a function that changes the whole page css, injecting a new styleSheet.

I have the following function:

```
loadCSS() {
        let fileRef;
        fileRef = document.createElement('link');
        fileRef.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        fileRef.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        fileRef.setAttribute('href', './appointment2.component.scss');
        if (typeof fileRef !== 'undefined') {
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileRef);
        }
    }
```

Once user click on this function, the new css style should be applied. But it does not happen.

I'm getting the following error: `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/appointment2.component.scss' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

I've already added the path to my @Component `styleUrls`:

```
    styleUrls: [
        './appointment2.component.scss',
        './appointment.component.scss'],
```

I've even already added it to my `styles` at `angular.json`:

```
"styles": [
    "src/app/appointment/appointment2.component.scss",
    "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
    "src/styles.scss",
    "src/theme.scss",
    "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
]
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

SASS (.scss) files are not valid CSS files.

They need to be transpiled into CSS first.

This means you can't use them in directly in your application.

Try providing a CSS (.css) file instead.

Comment: Also to be noted, what you're doing is a total antipattern : you're make an encapsulated style behave as a global style.

Comment: Not sure how CSS defined in the very project can be unsafe for a user but sure, whatever floats your boat

Comment: I tried with the .CSS file, but the same thing happened. Actually, the file is not even being found, look the [payload](https://prnt.sc/rYCwDru8c4Gl).

Answer (score 0):

With the great [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72561379/15843097) of [@temp_user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17740968) I discovered the file needed to be a '.CSS' file, and not '.SCSS'. But I was still getting one problem: The file could not be found (404 error at payload). So what I needed to do (besides changing the file format) was **Move the file to `/assets`** directory, and after this. Everything worked fine.

So, my code ended like this:

```
loadCSS() {
    let fileRef;
    fileRef = document.createElement('link');
    fileRef.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    fileRef.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    fileRef.setAttribute('href', '../../assets/dynamicStyles/appointment2.component.css');
    if (typeof fileRef !== 'undefined') {
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileRef);
    }
}
```

With this code, I'm able to change my page full style, anytime I need.

NOTE **It is not necessary** to add the file path in "styles" inside `angular.json`, nor in @Component inside my `app.component.ts`